Is MDC safe to use in spring async event listeners?
If we set a value in MDC using MDC.put, then publish an event using spring boot events (org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher), in the async listener the MDC value is unfortunately not set, because its in a new thread.
We use MDC for setting a correlationToken for logging, to tie all log lines for a particular set of actions.
If we instead do MDC.put and MDC.remove inside the listener, this would presumably work (i.e. the value would be logged if log.xxx is called), but what about concurrency?
Presumably various async listeners could be running at the same time, would they clobber each other, or would each get its own MDC context?
I.e. does each listener run always run in its own thread, i.e. its safe to use MDC (without other listeners running at the same time overwriting it)?
Note, java 8, spring boot 2.0.3, no special pools.
